# Rails migration performance: using 35GBs of swap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a pretty big migration scanning through a 300k-row table, using find_each and a batch_size of 1000.  The migration takes about two hours to run, and for each row a new row is created in a different table.  I can't use pure SQL to do this migration - it has to be Ruby.

My question, though, is why does Ruby first use up all the memory available and then start using insane amounts of swap (35GBs)?  (See the screen shots attached.)  I would have thought Ruby's GC would have been invoked before it started eating swap.  After all, in theory only 1000 records should be being loaded into memory at one time.  And these records are small, far smaller than 1MB.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: here's some sample code

```
Post.find_each(:batch_size => 1000) do |p|
  user = User.find_by_fb_id(p.fb_uid)
  if user
    puts "Migrating post #{p.pid}"
    e = Entity.new
    e.created_at = p.time
    e.updated_at = p.last_update
    e.response = p.post
    e.user_id = user.id
    e.legacy_type = "GamePost"
    e.legacy_id = p.pid
    e.is_approved = true
    e.is_muted = true
    e.save(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: @deceze, just updated the post with the code.

Comment: Ruby isnt using 35GB of swap... your whole computer is. Maybe you have something else going on? What else is your loop doing? You are essentially doing a straight copy, this should take a few minutes, not 2 hours.

Comment: @MitchDempsey, honestly that's it.  I quit every other program on my computer while this ran.  I'm not hiding any code from you, either.  I'm piping the output of the migration to a file, e.g. _rake db:migrate > /tmp/foo_.  But otherwise what you see is what I'm running.

Comment: One other thing, @MitchDempsey, the swap goes to 0 after the migration finishes.

Comment: Some Databases can be quite greedy in their processing. Which one are you using?

Comment: @alexlod if you aren't hiding any code, then why cant this be done with a single SQL query?

Comment: @mitch Entity.rb uses method_missing to field assignments 'response' and turn them into a JSON blob